# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'string' in mvc c#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor

I am new in MVC C#. I am getting this error, I have checked and found similar which is not going to my error.

The error is - *"Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'string'"*

The Code is -

```
List<RptItem> _r2 = _r1.Where(xx => xx.Value == ("rcat"))
            .Select(xx=>(KeyValuePair<string, string>?)xx)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Could someone help me, what I need to do.

Thanks

Comment: `xx.Value` seems to be `bool` type, thus cannot be possibly `"rcat"`. Check the `_r1` `T`

Comment: What is your definition for _r1? The error implies that xx.Value is a bool and you are trying to check it against a string.

Comment: _r1 is returing some dictionary value.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly like the error states, you are attempting to compare a [`bool`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8f5xwh7.aspx) (`xx.Value`) with a [`string`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) (`"rcat"`) which is not allowed for obvious reasons.

Comment: How can I change to string

Comment: What would be the meaning of converting `true/false` to a `string`? Especially when the `string` is `"rcat"` ? What exactly are you trying to attempt here?

Comment: I am trying to assign a dictionary value into a list, _r1 returning some dictionary value.

Answer (score 1):

In c# and pretty much every strongly typed language, you're forced to pass arguments of the correct **types** to functions, methods and operators. The operator '==' is typically overloaded to only accept two objects of the same type, and is therefor unable to compare an object of the type *string* to an object of the type *bool*.

You might be confused by the second part of your LINQ query: 
`.Select(xx=>(KeyValuePair<string, string>?)xx)`.

Just because you're casting `xx` to a `KeyValuePair<string, string>?` does not mean the `xx` value is of that type in the other scope: `(xx => xx.Value == ("rcat")`. The two `xx`'s are two different variables!

If you want to make `xx.Value` a string so that you can compare it with `"rcat"`, you can choose to call the function `ToString()` on `xx.Value` (although, since `xx.Value` is a boolean, calling this method will only generate strings equal to `"true"` or `"false"`).

Comment: Could you please give me an example please

Comment: I used xx => xx.Value == ("rcat").ToString but still getting the same error

Comment: ToString() transforms a object of any type to a string, so when you're calling it on "rcat", it's making a string... into a string! Your problem is that xx.Value is **not** a string, which it needs to be in order for you to compare the two. So, call ToString on xx.Value!

Comment: Well even if he does it wouldn't work since the reason you said yourself, it will compare `true`/`false` with `"rcat"` which won't help much...

Comment: is there any other way I can achieve the same result, where _r1 returing some dictionary value.

Comment: Yes, because your WHERE clause filters all records where `xx.Value` is not equal to "rcat", and then returns collection of those values casted to a KeyValue Pair. Whether or not this actually works depends entirely on your implementation of _r1.